# Suddenly "this.audiocontext.createScriptProcessor is not a function" error in p5js-sound

Tags: google-chrome, p5.js

I have a [website](http://bassfunk.moscow), that should play mp3 files after clicking on a logo. When a sound is played, the p5.js library ([p5js-sound](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/)) draws some graphic on the background. Suddenly it has stopped working. In the Chrome console log, the problem is with this [line](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/lib/addons/p5.sound.js#L2208). Without any reason after two years of working properly, it started to give this error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.audiocontext.createScriptProcessor is not a
>   function.

I found out that it works in Firefox and on some computers with older versions of Chrome.  How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does it work in Chrome canary/Opera? Could be a temporary bug in the version you're using (not entirely unusual when it comes to chrome..).

Answer (score 1):

Newest versions of Chrome will not "autoplay" audio. Some kind of user interaction is required, ie. click on something to "start" the audio context. When I get it to work I will post code.

Comment: Yes, I already downloaded new version of p5.sound.js, that fixed the problem. Btw it is the second time when chrome breaks something inside p5.js

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that this is a problem with your code or anything you have done to the p5.sound library.
On the contrary, it may be an out-of-date version of the library and the processing foundation may not have updated it yet.
 They are a non-profit organisation so cut them some slack but I suggest using an alternative library for now
You could use native functions like an onclick="" that controls whether a hidden <audio></audio> tag is playing - Good luck coding!